# What Anti-Virus for Windows Server?

Tags: windows-server-2003, anti-virus

I've been using AVG for my Windows 2003 Server boxes for the past few years. The subscription is about to expire and I'm wondering if there is something better with a similar price range. I believe I paid $150 for a 2 year 2 server license.

What anti-virus programs are available now for a windows server that is either free or low cost with a good track record?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/31235/should-i-run-an-antivirus-in-a-windows-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was asked on SuperUser - [Should I run an antivirus in a Windows Server?](https://superuser.com/questions/31235/should-i-run-an-antivirus-in-a-windows-server)

Several items have been pointed out there :)

Answer (score 4):

ClamWin works quite well, and is free.  On the paid front, NOD32 seems to be a quiet winner in lots of ways.

Comment: +1 for NOD32 (although you might find it called ESET Anti-Virus these days.)

Comment: thanks! my email program SmarterMail uses ClamAV so it must be decent.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought development of the windows port for Clam was stopped. Did they bring it back? If they did it's awesome.

Answer (score 3):

[ESET NOD32 Antivirus Business Edition](http://www.eset.com/products/nod32.php#nod32_business)
Highly regarded and small footprint.
I switched the AV on all Windows servers on my network to this from Symantec Endpoint Protection and I noticed a pretty good speed boost.
They have been very reasonable on renewal costs as well.

Comment: thanks for the extra info about Endpoint. After the prev answers about NOD32 I checked it out but it is a good bit more than Endpoint. Probably for good reason ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Symantec's Endpoint Protection Manager, it's actually quite cheap. look at the bundles on 3rd party sitges -- buycheapsoftware for example, not the single user costs on the Symantec site. I think we did 30 users for $300... and a user can be a server.

Answer (score 1):

[Spyware Terminator](http://www.spywareterminator.com/) is FREE and works integrated with ClamAV. It's the only good antispyware/antivirus free solution for Windows Server...

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft ForeFront](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/en/us/default.aspx)

It's not free, but definitely manageable within your Windows Domain. The ninja-admin can roll out the program automatically, and have updates sent out immediately.