# Free Windows server anti-virus and firewall programs?

Tags: windows-server-2003, firewall, anti-virus

What are some free Windows server anti-virus and firewall programs that can be installed at Windows Server 2003?

The primary services of my server is to host PHP websites and a few VB.NET socket servers.

Comment: um I'm creating this "accept-answer-in-a-week" tag. Will there be any punishment/bad-things-happened if I created a bad tag?

Comment: Every time you pick a bad tag, a kitten dies.

Comment: I'm sorry for the kitten.

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/2899/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/319/

Comment: Bad tags = code comments = dead kittens.  Save the kittens.  http://brianstestsite.googlepages.com/comments.JPG

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at ClamAV and ClamWin. It's a free and open source anti virus solution that (unlike many other free versions of commercial tools) runs under Windows Server.
One thing it lacks is an on-access scanner that checks files in real time. Guess you can't have it all ;-)

Answer (score 6):

OK, 5 steps.

1. Windows updates - This is your number 1 antivirus on Windows
2. Windows firewall - If you can't have additional firewall hardware this will do. Just learn how to use it via the command line.
3. Backups - Sorry guys, but no antivirus is 100% effective.
4. [Clam AntiVirus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clam_AntiVirus) - Nightly updates and full scans of your server with proper email alerts on update failures, virus detections and antivirus software failures.
5. Monitor eventlogs and move them off the server- nasty things tend to either show up here or break them. Use one of many syslog daemons available for Windows to move the logs to a remote host.
   Phew.. The hoops we have to jump though.

Comment: Sorry! but I couldn't help it. that's 5 steps. 5 helpful steps. =)

Answer (score 4):

1. I used the free version of [MalwareBytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malwarebytes%27_Anti-Malware).  It's exactly what I wanted in a virus scanner. It doesn't constantly run in the background hogging resources.  You open the application and click scan.  It properly removed a few viruses.
2. If you are looking for a one time scan the only online virus scan that I am aware of that will run on Windows 2003 Server is Trendmicro's [HouseCall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HouseCall).

Answer (score 4):

Try Comodo Internet Security - Free Version.
http://www.comodo.com/home/internet-security/free-internet-security.php

Answer (score 2):

I was able to load Microsoft Security Essentials Vista/Windows 7 64-bit on a Server 2003 x64.  Haven't run it for long, so I don't know yet if there are any issues regarding the platform mismatch, but it seems to install and run happily.  Your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, it is not real-time / on-access but it works:
 http://www.escanav.com/english/content/products/MWAV/escan_mwav.asp
Free eScanAV Anti-Virus Toolkit (MWAV) / Free Antivirus Download for XP, Vista & Windows 7
I am using it (together with ClamWin) on wk28 (windows 2008 server: webserver role: SP2

Answer (score 0):

FORTICLIENT ENDPOINT IS GOOD FOR FREE ON WINDOWS SERVER 2003