# How Can I install a free AntiVirus Scanner on my Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, anti-virus

I know this does not work impromptu. Is there a way of installing a free AV scanner?

I would prefer Microsoft Essentials or Antivir.

Answer (score 2):

You would install it just like any other Antivirus scanner, however, a lot of products such as Microsoft Security Eseentials are not designed for Server 2008 and will not install on it.

Just check operating system compatibility before you download. I am not sure of many free AV products that support a server OS simply because they sell business/enterprise products and just give away a consumer product for free in order to get their brand known.

Comment: can you recommend a free av tool?

Answer (score 1):

Over on Server Fault they've discused this issue a few times. Here is a link with several options for you. [what-anti-virus-for-windows-server](https://serverfault.com/questions/2899/what-anti-virus-for-windows-server)

Hope this helps some.

Answer (score 0):

One of the few free AV scanners I know that will work in Windows server is [Clam AV](http://www.clamwin.com/), however it does not do real time scanning, it only does scheduled scanning.